# POWERSHELL: Get password expiry date with UserPrincipal

Tags: powershell

I'm using UserPrincipal to gather details of local users on non-domain member servers. I want to email users when their passwords are expiring or expired.

I have everything except for the Max Password Age. I cannot get that value and everything I find talks about Active Directory connections which I don't need. When I try and adapt it to the local server, it doesn't work.

Here is what I have:

```
$date = Get-Date
$contextType = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine
$principalContext = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext($contextType)
$principalSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher(New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal($principalContext))

ForEach($userPrincipal in $principalSearcher.FindAll())
{
    $maxPasswordAge = 90

    $name = $userPrincipal.Name
    $samAccountName = $userPrincipal.SamAccountName
    $description = $userPrincipal.Description
    $fullname = $userPrincipal.DisplayName
    $lastPasswordSet = $userPrincipal.LastPasswordSet
    $passwordExpires = $lastPasswordSet.AddDays($maxPasswordAge)
    $passwordExpiresDays = New-TimeSpan -Start $date -End $passwordExpires
    $passwordExpiresDays = [Math]::Floor($passwordExpiresDays.TotalDays)

    Write-Host "Name: "$name
    Write-Host "SAM Account Name: "$samAccountName
    Write-Host "Full Name: "$fullName
    Write-Host "Password last set: "$lastPasswordSet
    Write-Host "Password expires: "$passwordExpiresDays
    Write-Host "Max Password Age: "$maxPasswordAge
}
```

In the code above I have manually set the value to 90 to get my code to work. I need to replace that with the code to retrieve the correct value.

I've tried the following to extract the DirectoryEntry object from my UserPrincipal, AND then the native object, but I cannot get it to work:

```
$directoryEntry = $userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject()
$native = [ADSI]$directoryEntry.NativeObject
```

I'm sure its easy and I have overlooked something obvious....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely not getting a value as password expiration for local user accounts is not enabled by default.

You would need to manually enable [Maximum password age](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994573(v=ws.11).aspx) in the computers Local Security Policy.

---

**EDIT**: You can read the value of the Local Security Policy setting from the registry:

```
$maxPasswordAge = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters -Name MaximumPasswordAge).MaximumPasswordAge
```

Comment: That would make sense code wise, but our user accounts do expire and require the password to be changed.

Comment: That seems to work, just testing and will get back to you. Thanks.